# Accessing Windows 7 shares - numerous issues

Tags: windows-7, samba

I am unable to access the shared folder of a Windows 7 machine on the same network.

I click on the network icon in places, then I can see the `Windows Network` option, but when I click on it, I get the message:

> Failed to retrieve share list from server

I've tried to install Samba (`sudo apt-get install samba`) and I've also installed SBMFS. I've set the workgroup in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to WORKGROUP - the same as the other Windows computers on the network. As far as I'm aware, I should now be able to get access to the shared folders on the Windows 7 computers, but no luck; I can't even get past the 'Windows Network' icon.

When I check the list of processes in the system monitor, there's no sign of anything called Samba or SMB. When I go to start S via `/etc/init.d/samba start`, I get the message

> command not found

As regards the network architecture, it's a simple home network running through a router, I don't know if it will make a difference, but the router is a D-Link DIR-615. Windows machines can share files without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file browser and type this in the loation bar `smb://ip-of-win7-machine/shared_dir`. Make relevant changes to the above command and it should work if you've configured the shares properly.

Answer (score 0):

In 'Places' Menu choose 'connect to server'. In the server type choose "windows share". Type the Ip of the Windows Machine in the server field and the name of the shared folder in the shared field.Hit connect. see whether you can access the shared folder now.

Answer (score 0):

I recently debugged an issue with a share on a Windows 7 machine, where a user had changed their password on the 7 box, but not on the XP box they were attempting to access the share from.  What threw me was that the share was invisible to every thing, until the user told me about the password change, at which point the share became accessible and visible.

I would recommend making sure the user credentials on the Linux machine match the user credentials on the 7 box.

Next I would go on to check the share data on the 7 box to make sure the user account you are wanting to use is allowed to access the share.